# Output a non-Context-Free Language

Tags: code-golf, string

Your challenge is to write a program which will output a non-context-free language.

A [Context-free Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) is a series of replacement rules, describing which symbols can be replaced by which other symbols. It defines set of strings, known as a language, which is generated by performing all possible replacement rules on an initial symbol until no more replacements can be made.

Any language which can be generated this way is known as a **context-free language**.

Your challenge is to write a program which will output a language which *cannot* be generated this way.

**Details**:

- Output your language in increasing order of length. Ordering between strings of a given length is up to you.
- As all CSLs are infinite, your program must not halt.
- The strings must be separated from each other. However, you may choose the separation.
- Please include in your answer a description of the language you generate and an explanation of why it is not context-free.
- One possible way to prove this is by using the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages).
- Example context-sensitive language: [abc, aabbcc, aaabbbccc, aaaabbbbcccc, ...]

**Scoring**: For all programs which can be encoded in ASCII or another 7 bit or less character set, scoring is by character. For all other programs, scoring is (# of bits in binary encoding)/7.

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Using your last example, what's to stop us from using something like the following (pseudocode based on various languages mashed together): `i = 1; while true { print ("a" * i) + ("b" * i) + ("c" * i) }`

Comment: I thought a context-sensitive language was one that could be produced be a context-sensitive grammar? Are you looking for one of these, or just something not context free?

Comment: Is this really to write a program that generates all strings in the language produced by a single context-sensitive lanaguge of the programmers choosing? That seems a poor challenge, as there are many trivial choices.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I meant non-context-free. I will change the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 6

I didn't find the Pyth documentation. But it works.

```
W1~ddd
```

Comment: Sorry about the lack of documentation - it's in progress.

Comment: Also, while I've seen programs whose code was all whitespace, that's the first one I've ever seen whose output was all whitespace. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 (24) <strike>(26)</strike>

```python
s="1"
while 1:print s;s+=s
```

Prints the language of strings in the symbol `1` whose length is a power of 2, i.e `{"1"*(2**n) | n>=0}`. The `s+=s` is equivalent to `s*=2`; it doubles the string each time.

Since unary (one-symbol) CFG's are regular, and unary regular CFG's are periodic past a point, this cannot be regular and thus is not a CFG. Alternatively, use the pumping lemma to see that the possible lengths of words in a CFL must have finite density and can't have arbitrarily large gaps.

Unfortunately, Python doesn't have a short way to produce an infinite counter. I'm sure some language can do `for i in Naturals:print("1"*i*i)` shorter (squares suffice just as well).

**Edit:** Can shorten to

```python
s=2
while 1:print s;s*=s
```

which prints numbers of the form `2**(2**n)`, which can be taken as strings over `0123456789`. Because the decimal length doubles at each step, this can't be context-free because the length gaps cannot satisfy the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <strike>8</strike> 7

```
{]`_p}h
```

It is not context-free because there are only at most 4 strings between length `n` and `7n` for any `n`.

It is context-sensitive because the memory usage is always growing, and it prints almost everything in the memory.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup, the problem should have said non-context-free.